Hosting a Django application on azure app service
After following the official host python with postgres tutorial, and making modifications in my gh actions file because my django apps isn't present in the root on the repo, I get a 404 error when trying to access it.
Here is my settings.py
"""
Django settings for server project.

Generated by 'django-admin startproject' using Django 5.0.3.

For more information on this file, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/settings/

For the full list of settings and their values, see
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/
"""

from decouple import config
from os import environ
from google.oauth2 import service_account

from pathlib import Path

from django.conf import global_settings

# Build paths inside the project like this: BASE_DIR / 'subdir'.
BASE_DIR = Path(__file__).resolve().parent.parent


# Quick-start development settings - unsuitable for production
# See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/deployment/checklist/

# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = config(
    "SECRET_KEY",
    default="django-insecure-g8khpcexyyb0q@p40^d5#r_j#ezf%(-90r-y^2@x1)2$wpch9+",
)

# SECURITY WARNING: don't run with debug turned on in production!
DEBUG = config("DEBUG", default=False, cast=bool)

ALLOWED_HOSTS = (
    [environ["WEBSITE_HOSTNAME"]]
    if "WEBSITE_HOSTNAME" in environ
    else config(
        "ALLOWED_HOSTS", cast=lambda v: [s.strip() for s in v.split(",")], default=[]
    )
)

CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS = config(
    "CORS_ALLOWED_ORIGINS",
    cast=lambda v: [s.strip() for s in v.split(",")],
    default="http://localhost:5173,http://127.0.0.1:5173",
)


# Application definition

INSTALLED_APPS = [
    "django.contrib.admin",
    "django.contrib.auth",
    "django.contrib.contenttypes",
    "django.contrib.sessions",
    "django.contrib.messages",
    "django.contrib.staticfiles",
    "rest_framework",
    "rest_framework.authtoken",
    "djoser",
    "corsheaders",
    "drf_spectacular",
    "accounts.apps.AccountsConfig",
    "videos.apps.VideosConfig",
]

MIDDLEWARE = [
    "django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware",
    "whitenoise.middleware.WhiteNoiseMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware",
    "corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware",
    "django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware",
    "django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware",
]

ROOT_URLCONF = "server.urls"

TEMPLATES = [
    {
        "BACKEND": "django.template.backends.django.DjangoTemplates",
        "DIRS": [],
        "APP_DIRS": True,
        "OPTIONS": {
            "context_processors": [
                "django.template.context_processors.debug",
                "django.template.context_processors.request",
                "django.contrib.auth.context_processors.auth",
                "django.contrib.messages.context_processors.messages",
            ],
        },
    },
]

WSGI_APPLICATION = "server.wsgi.application"


# Database
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#databases

DATABASES = {
    "default": {
        "ENGINE": config("DB_ENGINE", default="django.db.backends.sqlite3"),
        "NAME": config("DB_NAME", default=BASE_DIR / "db.sqlite3"),
        "USER": config("DB_USER", default=""),
        "PASSWORD": config("DB_PASSWORD", default=""),
        "HOST": config("DB_HOST", default=""),
        "PORT": config("DB_PORT", default=""),
    }
}


# Password validation
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#auth-password-validators

AUTH_PASSWORD_VALIDATORS = [
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.UserAttributeSimilarityValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.MinimumLengthValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.CommonPasswordValidator",
    },
    {
        "NAME": "django.contrib.auth.password_validation.NumericPasswordValidator",
    },
]

REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    "DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES": [
        "rest_framework.authentication.TokenAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.SessionAuthentication",
        "rest_framework.authentication.BasicAuthentication",  # simple cmd line tools can access the API
    ],
    "DEFAULT_SCHEMA_CLASS": "drf_spectacular.openapi.AutoSchema",
    "DEFAULT_PAGINATION_CLASS": "rest_framework.pagination.LimitOffsetPagination",
    "PAGE_SIZE": 100,
}


SPECTACULAR_SETTINGS = {
    "TITLE": "Video API",
    "DESCRIPTION": "Amalitech Video API",
    "VERSION": "1.0.0",
    "SERVE_INCLUDE_SCHEMA": False,
    # OTHER SETTINGS
}

DJOSER = {"PASSWORD_RESET_CONFIRM_URL": "password-reset-confirm/{uid}/{token}"}

EMAIL_HOST = config("EMAIL_HOST", default="localhost")
EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = config("EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD", default="")
EMAIL_HOST_USER = config("EMAIL_HOST_USER", default="")
EMAIL_PORT = config("EMAIL_PORT", default=25, cast=int)
EMAIL_USE_TLS = config("EMAIL_USE_TLS", default=False, cast=bool)

# Internationalization
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/topics/i18n/

LANGUAGE_CODE = "en-us"

TIME_ZONE = "UTC"

USE_I18N = True

USE_TZ = True


# Static files (CSS, JavaScript, Images)
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/howto/static-files/

STATIC_URL = "static/"

STATIC_ROOT = BASE_DIR / "static"

SESSION_ENGINE = "django.contrib.sessions.backends.cache"
STATICFILES_STORAGE = "whitenoise.storage.CompressedManifestStaticFilesStorage"

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = config(
    "DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE", default=global_settings.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE
)

GS_CREDENTIALS = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file(
    BASE_DIR / "serviceaccount.json"
)

GS_BUCKET_NAME = config("GS_BUCKET_NAME", default="")
GS_DEFAULT_ACL = config("GS_DEFAULT_ACL", default="")

# Default primary key field type
# https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/settings/#default-auto-field

DEFAULT_AUTO_FIELD = "django.db.models.BigAutoField"


and the gh action used to deploy to app service
# Docs for the Azure Web Apps Deploy action: https://github.com/Azure/webapps-deploy
# More GitHub Actions for Azure: https://github.com/Azure/actions
# More info on Python, GitHub Actions, and Azure App Service: https://aka.ms/python-webapps-actions

name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - plvids

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./apps/server
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Create settings.ini file
        run: |
          echo [settings] >> settings.ini
          echo "ALLOWED_HOSTS = ${{ secrets.ALLOWED_HOSTS }}" >> settings.ini
          echo "SECRET_KEY = ${{ secrets.SECRET_KEY }}" >> settings.ini
          echo "DB_NAME = ${{ secrets.DBNAME }}" >> settings.ini
          echo "DB_USER = ${{ secrets.DBUSER }}" >> settings.ini
          echo "DB_PASSWORD = ${{ secrets.DBPASSWORD }}" >> settings.ini
          echo "DB_ENGINE = ${{ secrets.DB_ENGINE }}" >> settings.ini
          echo "DB_HOST = ${{ secrets.DBHOST }}" >> settings.ini
          echo "DB_PORT = ${{ secrets.DBPORT }}" >> settings.ini
          echo "DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = ${{ secrets.DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE }}" >> settings.ini
          echo "EMAIL_HOST = ${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST }}" >> settings.ini
          echo "EMAIL_PORT = ${{ secrets.EMAIL_PORT }}" >> settings.ini
          echo "EMAIL_HOST_USER = ${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST_USER }}" >> settings.ini
          echo "EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD = ${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD }}" >> settings.ini
          echo "GS_BUCKET_NAME = ${{ secrets.EMAIL_HOST_PASSWORD }}" >> settings.ini
          echo "GS_DEFAULT_ACL = ${{ secrets.GS_DEFAULT_ACL }}" >> settings.ini
          echo '${{secrets.GS_SERVICE_ACCOUNT}}' >> serviceaccount.json
        shell: bash

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate

      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      # Optional: Add step to run tests here (PyTest, Django test suites, etc.)

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            ./apps/server/release.zip
            !venv/

  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    permissions:
      id-token: write #This is required for requesting the JWT

    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      - name: Login to Azure
        uses: azure/login@v1
        with:
          client-id: ${{ secrets.*** }}
          tenant-id: ${{ secrets.*** }}
          subscription-id: ${{ secrets.*** }}

      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: '***'
          slot-name: 'Production'


the logs in app service don't show anything
build logs show successful building without any errors
This is a link to the repository

If possible, share your repository here.

@AsleshaKantamsetti updated with GitHub repo

Navigate to KUDU site(https://videoplatform30.scm.azurewebsites.net/newui) of the web app and check the logs in Log Stream.


I have deployed your Django project to Azure and got it working as expected.
GitHub Workflow:
name: Build and deploy Python app to Azure Web App - appname

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main
  workflow_dispatch:

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    defaults:
      run:
        working-directory: ./apps/server
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v4

      - name: Set up Python version
        uses: actions/setup-python@v1
        with:
          python-version: '3.11'

      - name: Create and start virtual environment
        run: |
          python -m venv venv
          source venv/bin/activate
      
      - name: Install dependencies
        run: pip install -r requirements.txt

      - name: Zip artifact for deployment
        run: zip release.zip ./* -r

      - name: Upload artifact for deployment jobs
        uses: actions/upload-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app
          path: |
            ./apps/server/release.zip
            !venv/
  deploy:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    needs: build
    environment:
      name: 'Production'
      url: ${{ steps.deploy-to-webapp.outputs.webapp-url }}
    
    steps:
      - name: Download artifact from build job
        uses: actions/download-artifact@v3
        with:
          name: python-app

      - name: Unzip artifact for deployment
        run: unzip release.zip

      
      - name: 'Deploy to Azure Web App'
        uses: azure/webapps-deploy@v2
        id: deploy-to-webapp
        with:
          app-name: 'appname'
          slot-name: 'Production'
          publish-profile: ${{ secrets.AZUREAPPSERVICE_PUBLISHPROFILE_7793CXXXX4DA }}


Deployed to Python Azure App Service(Linux) using GitHub actions:



Able to run the application:




did you have to make any changes to any files?

probably my env variables were the problem, since you didn't have that in the action.yml file

No, I didn't change anything.

I dont want to use github actions, I want to you Azure devops piplelines, what shall I do. Any yaml file example ?
